# Find the radius of convergence of a series centered at a point

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

> a) Let $f(z) = \sum_{n≥0} z^n$. Find the radius of convergence of the series.
>
> b) For all $t \epsilon \mathbb R$, $t<1$, find the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $t$. (Hint: let $w = z-t$ and write $f(z) = f(w+t)$)

My attempts:

a) The radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, where $\alpha := lim_{n→\inf}$ sup n$\sqrt{|a_n|}$.

But here $|a_n| = 1$ and so the limit (as defined above) is equal to $1$.

Hence $R=1$

b)$f(z) = f(w+t)$ = $\sum_{n≥0} {(t+w)}^n$ = $\sum_{n≥0} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n} {k} t^{n-k} w^k$

But $\binom{n} {k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Let $a_n = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$
And so lim as $n$ tends to infinity of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$.

And hence $R=1$

Are my attemps correct? Any other solutions please? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your answer for (a) is correct. For (b) I think is correct and here is another way, let $1 > t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then the expansion of $f$ centered at $t$ is
$$ \sum_{n \geq 0} (z-t)^n $$
Which as you've already shown, converges for $|z-t|<1$.  Let $z=x+iy$, then $f$ converges on the set
$$ \{z : |z-t|<1 \} = \{ z : |z-t|^2<1 \} = \{ x+iy : (x-t)^2 + y^2 <1 \} $$
which is exactly the open disc of radius $1$ centered at $t$. So radius of convergence is $R=1$

Comment: The answer to (b) is wrong. Imagine, for example, $t=0.5$. If the radius of convergence were $R=1$, then you're saying that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ converges (on the real line) on the interval $(-0.5,1.5)$, which clearly isn't true.

Comment: So what would be the correct answer for part b)?

Comment: @zipirovich what could we do in part b